Kernel for Ubuntu 24.04.1 doesn't boot
Installed 24.04.1 yesterday 9-4-24 on a machine with 23.10 installed. During the installed 'upgrade' had a couple error messages, one I fixed the other was about broken packages for Thunderbird...which I never use. But I followed the onscreen instructions and then went back to my chores while it finished the install. I expected it to reboot, but it didn't. Just showed my regular desktop. Eventually I rebooted...when it past bios and the Grub screens, hung up on the IRQ discovery page. Cursor not blinking. After 40 minutes, nothing changed.
During testing, I found that I could drop back to the 6.5.0-44-generic kernel and it'll boot to the desktop. If I try to boot to 6.8.0-41-generic, it'll lock up.
I did run boot repair but it didn't seem to fix anything.
Any way to fix this so it boots to the correct newer kernel without locking up? Should I delete the -44 kernel?
Thanks.
EDIT: Screwed up during Boot-repair and the drive won't boot at all now, so cloned it from my backup drive.

My post DOES show 23.10. That's what I had, then upgraded to 24.04.1.

use boot-repair advanced options, and select "purge the kernel and install the latest"
